# Running CMD entered comand in entrypoint results in exited with code 0

Tags: php, linux, docker, docker-compose, devops

I run my Dockerfile (through docker-compose) with my own entry point. At the end I would like to run a command from CMD. Unfortunately the command is not launched I don't know why. I don't know what I do wrong.
My entrypoint:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf &

/usr/sbin/crond &

su - www-data

exec "$@"
```

My Dockerfile

```sh
EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT "/root/entrypoint.sh"

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

When I run the docker-compose up I see that: `api_1 exited with code 0`. I tried running `echo "$@"` and it returns empty string. What can I do to make the php-fpm start? Is this the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the user www-data on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you use ENTRYPOINT without [] the instruction from CMD is not passed to entrypoint script. I changed ENTRYPOINT to `ENTRYPOINT ["/root/entrypoint.sh"]` and now everything is working fine :)